# Impossible to create a new pokestop in a new rural development

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a new rural development that has exploded with new residences and one paper, it has a number of community park and gathering areas that seemed to me to be prime pokestop locations.

For instance,

- an open grass area next to a pond that is used for exercising and community gatherings such as picnics. It's in a safe area, easily accessible to the public, safe to access, is a place to interact with others in the community and be outdoors.
- a lake which has a walking track around it to encourage people to exercise. Once again, safe to access, public area.
- a community gathering spot of rocks, specifically installed for people to sit and talk. It's basically where a playground SHOULD be but the council was too cheap to install any playground equipment or anything more than a circle of rocks next to a grassed area.

There are no signs, plaque and never will be (see point above about the council being cheap). There is no artwork or other installations and there never will be (see point above about the council being cheap). We won't have these markers but as far as the developers and council is concerned, that is all the community needs for parks and exercise.

I have tried to explain this in my pokestop submissions but so far I have received quick rejections with not much information on why they are rejected other than it does not meet the criteria. The thing is, I was sure that it did meet the criteria but with no information on WHAT criteria these points not meet, there is nothing I knowingly can do that can improve their understanding that these are genuine submissions with the only options for people to access pokestops in an entire town community (yes, there are none in that community). No one is going to drive 30kms to reach their nearest pokestop to spin it.

So what are your thoughts or advice on how can these three options (they are the only options as we have no signs or markers or other things of note to use for this community, not even common services like post offices, libraries or shops...all a drive away).

Comment: Hi AM, your question in the last paragraph is interrupted by parentheses and never is continued; can you fix that? I believe that if the locations you mention meet the requirements and still get rejected, that is a problem only the company can fix.

Answer (score 4):

As you wrote "There are no signs, plaque and never will be", so that's the sad point. Those submissions will never be accepted without a real location with a name, because you can't have a pokestop called "lake" or "grass area near a pond".

You may need to find something else, like an old fountain, a statue, a church, the post office, an information sign about the geographic area...

Comment: + If there's a walking track there could be distance markers of some sort, even just little yellow or blue bumps on the pavement or little poles off to the side. Parks, benches/Gazebos/Other 'outdoorsy' structures could be named without a dedicated plaque for them, check Google Maps and/or the town's information center/signs. PoGo much prefers "Walter J. Smith Memorial Park Gazebo" as a name over just "Gazebo"